# Airflow tasks with different schedules in the same dag

Tags: airflow

I would like to have some tasks running every day and others running every week inside the same DAG, is it possible or should I create a different DAG for different schedule tasks ?

I have seen the solution of using `ShortCircuitOperator` or `AirflowSkipException` and I was wondering if it is a good practice or a means of bypassing limitations of Airflow. Finally my question would be : is using `ShortCircuitOperator` or `AirflowSkipException` acceptable or using a new DAG is preferable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a DAG that scheduler a monthly job together with a daily job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57104547/how-to-define-a-dag-that-scheduler-a-monthly-job-together-with-a-daily-job)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have seen this solution and I was wondering if it is a good practice or a means of bypassing limitations of Airflow. Finally my question would be : is using `ShortCircuitOperator` or `AirflowSkipException` acceptable or using a new DAG is preferable ?

Comment: @ValentinRicher: Did you find an appropriate solution for this scenario?

Comment: Yes, I think creating two separate DAGs is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587355/10981911).

In short, configure the task-specific `start_date` parameter, introduce dependencies, or use pools to segregate tasks by runtime/priority.

Comment: Thank you but the solutions proposed do not apply :
1. Modifying the start_date for each task is not a good thing to do
2. Using pools to starve some tasks and favour others is not possible because it is not a question of how fast some tasks perform compared to others
3. And `priority weight` won't do the job as I need a precise schedule