# Task timeout for Airflow DAGs

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running 5 PythonOperator tasks in my airflow DAG and one of them is performing an ETL job which is taking a long time, due to which all my resources are blocked. Is there a way I can set a max execution time per task, after which the task either fails or is marked successful (so that the DAG doesnt fail) with a message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In every operator we have an `execution_timeout` variable where you have to pass a `datetime.timedelta` object.

As per the [base operator code comments](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py):

```
:param execution_timeout: max time allowed for the execution of
    this task instance, if it goes beyond it will raise and fail.
:type execution_timeout: datetime.timedelta
```

Also bear in mind that this will fail a single run of the DAG and will trigger re-runs and will only be declared to be a failed DAG when all re-runs have failed.

So depending on what number of auto retries you have assigned, you could have a potential maximum time of `( number of retries ) x ( timeout )` in case the code keeps taking too long.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587355/10981911)

In short, using airflow's built in [pools](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#pools) or even specifying a [start_date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660732/airflow-why-is-there-a-start-date-for-operators/48675923#48675923) for a task (instead of an entire DAG) seem to be potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

From [this documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/tasks.html), you'd want to set the `execution_timeout` task parameter, which would look something like this

```py
from datetime import timedelta

sensor = SFTPSensor(
    task_id="sensor",
    path="/root/test",
    execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
    timeout=3600,
    retries=2,
    mode="reschedule",
)
```